# Cannot use hybrid GPU mode in Fedora installation, works fine with the live ISO. Ideas?

Tags: fedora, nvidia, intel, gpu, hybrid-graphics

My laptop is the Legion 5 Pro 16IAH7H Laptop from Lenovo. It has two graphic cards:

- iGPU of the Intel i7-12700H processor
- dGPU Nvidia RTX 3070

For some reason, hybrid mode works fine in Fedora Workstation 38 live… but not in my installation, that's exactly Fedora Workstation 38!

Using the live ISO both cards are listed.
On the contrary, the installed Fedora only show the Intel card:

```
[gremo@fedora ~]$ switcherooctl list
Device: 0
  Name:        Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics
  Default:     yes
  Environment: DRI_PRIME=pci-0000_00_02_0
```

However, Nvidia card is detected with `lspci` and I've installed the proprietary drivers successfully. You may ask to try with neuveau driver as the live ISO: doesn’t work either.

```
[gremo@fedora ~]$ lspci -n -n -k | grep -A 2 -e VGA -e 3D
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:46a6] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3aed]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q] [10de:24dd] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3833]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Any idea what the problem could be?